# Haxe Error: You cannot access the cpp package while targeting cross (for cpp.Lib)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, target, haxe

I was trying to set up Haxe, but this error faces me whenever I try to import a Library, whether it be `js.Lib`, `cpp.Lib`, etc. It always comes up with this error:

> Error: You cannot access the cpp package while targeting cross (for cpp.Lib)

[image: Screenshot]

I've been searching for hours now, with nobody seeming to get the same problem and no fixes. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"cross" means that the compiler is being invoked without any target (`-cpp`, `-js`...) specified.

I'm not sure which one you selected, but if I remember correctly, the project setup with some of HaxeDevelop's templates is a bit unusual. Normally you would use a [HXML file](https://haxe.org/manual/compiler-usage-hxml.html) where you can specify the arguments directly. A `build.hxml` that looks like this should work here:

```
-cp src
-main Main
-cpp bin
```

Then just run `haxe build.hxml`.